# ASP.NET Core - Key Not Found Upon Execute Command

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to connect to my local database - which I can access using localhost/phpmyadmin - using ASP.NET Core. I'm new to the language, and I am struggling with a MySQL-related exception.

```
string constr = Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:con").Value;
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
{
    string query = @"SELECT id
                    FROM `test`";
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (var sqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (sqlDataReader.Read())
            {
                var id = sqlDataReader.GetInt32(0);
            }
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

The exception happens at the line *using (var sqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())*.

This is my connection string:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "con": "Server=localhost;Database=musense;User=root;Password=********;Charset=utf8"
 }
```

I am setting the connection string from within the appsettings.json. Without the charset, I get an exception that "'windows-1252' is not a supported encoding name."

Upon running the above code, I get the following exception at the line *using (var sqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())*.:

```
/home/memonick/Documents/Projects/musense/musense.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'MySql.Data 6.9.9' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
/home/memonick/Documents/Projects/musense/musense.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'MySql.Data 6.9.9' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

Unhandled Exception: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException()
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlField.SetFieldEncoding()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetColumnData(MySqlField field)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetColumnsData(MySqlField[] columns)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetColumns(Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.LoadColumns(Int32 numCols)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet..ctor(Driver d, Int32 statementId, Int32 numCols)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.Close()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ResetReader()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at musense.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in /home/memonick/Documents/Projects/musense/Startup.cs:line 46
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   at musense.Program.BuildWebHost(String[] args) in /home/memonick/Documents/Projects/musense/Program.cs:line 21
   at musense.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/memonick/Documents/Projects/musense/Program.cs:line 17
```

It's worth noting that the connection is being established. Thus, for example, I can update a row, or execute SELECT VERSION(). The problem happens only when I try to execute a SELECT statement on a table from ASP.NET Core. The statement itself seems valid, as it executes normally in phpmyadmin.

The test table has the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci;
```

I've tried various collations, but the exception persists. Any help is welcome!

Comment: MySQL connector return a value that you can compare with DBNull.Value. It's look like database is returning a null value from the record.

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta Which connector should return a value?

Comment: I assume it's your primary key, does it exist. because if it's null it will be making typecast exception and your exception suggesting something like nothing is returned on 0 index.

Comment: I only have one record - the _id_ (primary key) is 1, and the _value_ (the other column) is 12. As I wrote, executing _SELECT id FROM test_ in phpmyadmin returns the row successfully.

Comment: Your issue seems to originate here: `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlField.SetFieldEncoding`, the driver doesn't find the encoding you provided inside its dictionary. From what I can see you are using a nuget package which is not fully compatible with .netstandard, this may be the cause of the issue. Which version of `MySql.Data` are you using?

Comment: I didn't see it was already in your question. `MySql.Data 6.9.9` is not designed to be used in `.NET Core`, please upgrade it and use at least `6.10.3-rc` version (you need to check *show prerelease packages* in nuget browser), and then try again.

Comment: That's great! Thank you @FedericoDipuma ^_^ How may I mark your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue rises by the fact that you are using a NuGet package not compatible with `.NETCoreApp2.0`:

```
/home/memonick/Documents/Projects/musense/musense.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'MySql.Data 6.9.9' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

You need to upgrade `MySql.Data 6.9.9` and use at least `6.10.3-rc` version (remember to check *show prerelease packages* in nuget browser), which is compatible with `.netstandard1.3` and above (including `.NETCoreApp2.0`).