# Unable to connect to MySQL on ASP.Net Core 2.0

Tags: mysql-connector, asp.net-core-2.0

I created a new Asp.Net core 2.0 project, added MySql.Data
When I try:

```
mySqlConnection.Open();
```

then this exception occurs:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectAttrs.get_OSDetails()
>   TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, bool constructor)

I searched and did not find System.Management on NuGet for ASP.Net Core.

Also on the Dependencies (References),
This shows on:

> Package 'MySql.Data.6.9.9' was restored using
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework
>   '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible
>   with your project.

How to connect to MySQL using Nuget on this situation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46015751/194717

Answer (score 1):

For the .net core only the pre-release nugets work. As of now the latest version is 8.0.8-dmr. To access these you can either check the "include prereleases" option in your nuget manager or for packet manager you can use:

```
Install-Package MySql.Data -Version 8.0.8-dmr
```

Or on CLI you can use:

```
dotnet add package MySql.Data --version 8.0.8-dmr
```

Comment: What this **dmr** stands for? I know that these releases are not stable. But why this convention.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-development-cycle/en/development-milestone-releases.html