# ERROR: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts - Synology NAS - MariaDB 10 - C#

Tags: c#, mysql, mariadb

I have a problem to connect my C# application in Visual Studio 2019 to Database inside Snyology NAS using MariaDB 10. If I connected the Database with HeidiSQL works good, but if I try to connect C# App with the same credentials I see an error like this:

"Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts"

I tried to check and I verified that:

- TCP functionality is enable on Synology NAS
- User and password are correct and I have all the privileges
- Database name is correct
- Port is also correct 3307 (setting default on Synology)

This is the code that I use to check the connection:

```
string connectionString = "";
string server = "ip_address_NAS:3307";
string database = "my_Database";
string username = "my_user";
string password = "my_password";

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection cn;

connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";DATABASE=" + database + ";UID=" + username + ";PASSWORD=" + password;          
            
try
{

cn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connectionString);                
cn.Open();                
label1.Text = "Database ONLINE!";                
label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;                
cn.Close();
            
}
            
catch(Exception ex)            
{
                
label1.Text = "Database OFFLINE!\n" + ex.Message;                
label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            
}
```

Why this error?
Can you help me? please.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the port number from the hostname. If you are connecting to the default port, there's no need to specify a port. If you are connecting to a custom port, it has to be defined in the following way

```
Server=myServerAddress;Port=1234;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword
```

[Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-8-0-connection-options.html)

**Edit**

3307 is *not* the default port for MySQL or MariaDB. So if your database is running on port 3307 (because for whatever reason Synology has chosen it to be the initial setting) you need to specify that port in the connection string. But not as part of the servername but with the `Port=3307` property.

Comment: I get the same error...if I remove the port

Comment: If I use port=3307 ...I get another error "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation"

Comment: With that type of exception there's is typically some additional information available.

Comment: I put MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); but I get only "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation"

Comment: Please add a debugger and inspect the exception. There are things like a stacktrace and possibly an `InnerException` which hold additional information

Comment: I would to specify that I am connecting with OpenVPN to my LAN (where it is linked the NAS), but in general it should be work fine because if I digit in my browser the IP address of the NAS I can find it, or if I use HeidiSQL it works fine, It means that I am virtually inside the LAN with open VPN

Comment: That should not be a problem. If you can reach your Nas with the correct ip with other applications, also a c# app should work

Comment: If I use the InnerException I can read this: 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Unable to find the specified file.
File name: 'System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectAttrs.get_OSDetails()

Comment: Hm, not sure about this, but maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46307053/unable-to-connect-to-mysql-on-asp-net-core-2-0

Comment: Ok, now It works fine! I downloaded and put as reference the System.Management.dll file into project !